# Wait for hook finishes updating component before passing value to a form

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I've been having a following problem lately. I want to create simple panel for adding new articles or news to my app using Firebase. I created a custom hook for getting the highest current article ID and it seems to be working properly. Unfortunately when I am using it in admin panel component the first value (that's undefined or NaN) is being passed to the form. I want this value to be displayed as a part of the form, being a disabled input. As text input I created a custom and stylized component, where I am only passing the values I need. How can I make it wait for the hook to update (i.e. get an actual value from DB) and then pass it to the Input component?
Worth mention: Typescript is preventing me from using

```
if (highestID === NaN) { return }
```

saying that type number | undefined does not exist in type number.

Here's my useGetHighestId.ts hook

```
import { db } from "../config/firebaseConfig";
import { collection, query, doc, getDoc, getDocs, DocumentSnapshot } from "firebase/firestore";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { ArticleParameters } from "../AdminPanel/AdminPanel";

export const useHighestId = (category?: string): number => {
  const [allCategories, setAllCategories] = useState<any[]>([]);
  const [articlesList, setArticlesList] = useState<any>({});
  const [highestId, setHighestId] = useState<number>(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getCategory = async () => {
      const collectDataFromDB = query(collection(db, "content"));
      const dataFromDB: any[] = [];
      const documents = await getDocs(collectDataFromDB);
      documents.docs.map((document) => {
        dataFromDB.push(document.id);
      });
      setAllCategories(dataFromDB);
    };
    getCategory();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    allCategories.map((currentCategory) => {
      const getArticlesFromDB = async () => {
        const docRef = doc(db, "content", currentCategory);
        const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);
        setArticlesList(docSnap.data());
      };
      getArticlesFromDB();
    });
  }, [allCategories]);

  const articlesListAsArray: ArticleParameters[] = Object.values(articlesList);
  const articlesIds: number[] = [];

  articlesListAsArray.forEach((article) => {
    articlesIds.push(article?.id);
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    if (articlesIds.sort().reverse()[0] !== undefined) {
      setHighestId(articlesIds.sort().reverse()[0]);
    }
  }, [articlesIds]);

  return highestId;
};
```

Here is the implementation of the admin panel:

```
import { useUser } from "../hooks/useUser";
import { db, storage } from "../config/firebaseConfig";
import { doc, setDoc, collection, getDocs, addDoc, query, Timestamp, updateDoc } from "firebase/firestore";
import { ChangeEvent, FormEvent, FormEventHandler, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Button, Col, Form, FormCheck, Row } from "react-bootstrap";
import { TextInput } from "../utils/TextInput";
import { useHighestId } from "../hooks/useHighestId";
import { getDownloadURL, ref, uploadBytesResumable } from "firebase/storage";

export interface ArticleParameters {
  category: string;
  id: number;
  title: string;
  content: string;
  author: string;
  date: Timestamp;
  tags: string[];
  isOnline: boolean;
  isAdult: boolean;
  databaseTitle: string;
}

const currentDate = new Date();

export const AdminPanel = () => {
  const user = useUser();
  let highestIdFromHook = useHighestId();

  const parameters: ArticleParameters = {
    category: "news",
    id: highestIdFromHook + 1,
    title: "",
    content: "",
    author: "",
    date: Timestamp.fromDate(currentDate),
    tags: [""],
    isOnline: false,
    isAdult: false,
    databaseTitle: "",
  };

  const [data, setData] = useState<ArticleParameters>(parameters);
  const [articleDatabaseName, setArticleDatabaseName] = useState<string>(`${data.category}_id_${data.id}`);
  const [file, setFile] = useState<any>("");
  const [percent, setPercent] = useState<number>(0);

  // Handle file upload event and update state
  function handleChange(event: any) {
    setFile(event.target.files[0]);
  }

  const handleUpload = () => {
    const storageRef = ref(storage, `/files/${file.name}`);

    // progress can be paused and resumed. It also exposes progress updates.
    // Receives the storage reference and the file to upload.
    const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, file);

    uploadTask.on(
      "state_changed",
      (snapshot) => {
        const percent = Math.round((snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100);

        // update progress
        setPercent(percent);
      },
      (err) => console.log(err),
      () => {
        // download url
        getDownloadURL(uploadTask.snapshot.ref).then((url) => {
          console.log(url);
        });
      }
    );
  };

  const addArticle = async (newArticleData: ArticleParameters) => {
    await updateDoc(doc(db, "content", newArticleData.category), {
      [newArticleData.databaseTitle]: {
        id: newArticleData.id,
        title: newArticleData.title,
        content: newArticleData.content,
        author: newArticleData.author,
        date: newArticleData.date,
        tags: newArticleData.tags,
        is_online: newArticleData.isOnline,
        is_adult: newArticleData.isAdult,
      },
    });
  };

  const handleSwitch = (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setData({ ...data, [e.target.name]: e.target.checked });
  };

  //   const handleChange = (e: any) => {
  //     setFile(e.target.files[0]);
  //   };

  const { category, id, title, content, author, date, tags, isOnline, isAdult } = data;

  const resetForm = () => {
    setArticleDatabaseName(`${data.category}_id_${data.id}`);
    setData({
      category: "news",
      id: highestIdFromHook + 1,
      title: "",
      content: "",
      author: "",
      date: Timestamp.fromDate(currentDate),
      tags: [""],
      isOnline: false,
      isAdult: false,
      databaseTitle: articleDatabaseName,
    });
  };

  const handleSubmit = (e: FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!file) {
      alert("Please upload an image first!");
    }
    if (data.databaseTitle !== "") {
      addArticle(data);
      handleUpload();
      resetForm();
    } else {
      console.log("Shit");
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="articles__content--wrapper">
      <h1 className="text-center mb-4">Dodaj newsa</h1>
      <Form
        style={{
          width: "80%",
          alignSelf: "center",
          alignItems: "center",
        }}
        onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <TextInput input="Tytuł" isRequired="true" type="text" name="title" data={data} setData={setData} />
        <TextInput input="Treść" isRequired="true" type="text" name="content" data={data} setData={setData} textarea />
        <Form.Group controlId="formFile" className="mb-3">
          <Form.Label>Dodaj obrazek</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control className="form__control--input" type="file" accept="image/*" onChange={handleChange} />
        </Form.Group>
        <div style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "row", justifyContent: "space-between", alignItems: "center" }}>
          <TextInput input="Data dodania" isRequired="true" disabled type="text" name="date" data={data} setData={setData} />
          <TextInput input="ID Newsa" isRequired="true" disabled type="number" name="id" data={data} setData={setData} />
          <div style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "column", justifyContent: "space-between", alignItems: "flex-start" }}>
            <Form.Check type="switch" label="Opublikować?" id="isOnline" name="isOnline" onChange={handleSwitch} className="me-3"></Form.Check>
            <Form.Check type="switch" label="Tylko dla dorosłych?" id="isAdult" name="isAdult" onChange={handleSwitch} className="mb-3 me-3"></Form.Check>
          </div>
        </div>
        <TextInput input="Autor" isRequired="true" disabled type="text" name="author" data={data} setData={setData} />
        <TextInput input="Nazwa w bazie" isRequired="true" disabled type="text" name="databaseTitle" data={data} setData={setData} />
        <div style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "row", justifyContent: "space-around", alignItems: "center" }}>
          <Button variant="info" type="submit">
            Zapisz dane
          </Button>
          <Button variant="warning" type="reset" onClick={resetForm}>
            Wyczyść formularz
          </Button>
        </div>
      </Form>
    </div>
  );
};
```

and the TextInput itself:

```
import FloatingLabel from "react-bootstrap/FloatingLabel";
import Form from "react-bootstrap/Form";
import { Dispatch, SetStateAction } from "react";
import { ArticleParameters } from "../AdminPanel/AdminPanel";
import { useUser } from "../hooks/useUser";

export interface DispatchTypes {
  nickname?: string;
  email: string;
  password: string;
  error?: string;
}

interface Properties {
  input: string;
  isRequired: string;
  type: string;
  name: string;
  data: any;
  setData: Dispatch<SetStateAction<DispatchTypes>> | Dispatch<SetStateAction<ArticleParameters>> | any;
  textarea?: boolean;
  disabled?: boolean;
}

export const TextInput = ({ input, isRequired, type, name, data, setData, textarea, disabled }: Properties) => {
  const user = useUser();
  
  const handleChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setData({ ...data, [name]: e.target.value });
  };

  if (name === "author" && user?.name !== undefined) {
    data.author = user?.name;
  }
  if (name === "databaseTitle") {
    data.databaseTitle = `${data.category}_id_${data.id}`
  }

  return (
    <FloatingLabel  label={`${input}${isRequired === "true" ? "*" : " (opcjonalnie)"}`} className="mb-3" style={{fontSize: "0.75rem"}}>
      <Form.Control
        as={textarea ? "textarea" : 'input'}
        style={textarea ? {height: "200px", fontSize: "1rem"} : { height: "45px", fontSize: "1rem"}}
        className="form__control--input"
        type={type}
        placeholder={`${name}${isRequired === "true" ? "*" : " (opcjonalnie)"}`}
        required={isRequired === "true" ? true : false}
        disabled={disabled ? true : false}
        name={name}
        onChange={handleChange}
        value={name === "date" ? data.date.toDate() : data[name]}
      />
    </FloatingLabel>
  );
};
```

Comment: I think you've added two times the `useHighestId` hook and not the admin panel part - probably some context is missing right now.

Comment: Sorry, I have corrected that

Answer (score 0):

Since `highestId` is defaulted to 0 in the hook fetching categories, why don't you add the check `if(highestID <= 0) return null` in the `AdminPanel` - this way you will start rendering once the hook has returned a value.

Comment: This is what I am getting in my Router: 'AdminPanel' cannot be used as a JSX component.
  Its return type 'Element | undefined' is not a valid JSX element.
    Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Element | null'

Comment: Well if this is the type then just use `return null` - it is the same for react in the end.

Comment: Did this one worked out? I've edited my answer

Comment: Actually I went with an useEffect hook, but used a null return as you suggested. For the time being I set the return type of the component to any, I will figure this out later how to type it properly.

Comment: But then you have coupled `useEffect` hooks and the second one is generating an additional useless render.  Just FYI

Comment: If you think your solution is better - you could post an answer and approve it yourself but it is not fair approach to others to abandon the question once you have found an answer.

Comment: I'm still working on it as well as I wait for maybe another approaches